# How to not show intermediate screen and call viewWillAppear when we are dismissing two view controllers back

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, segue, unwind-segue

Let's say I have 3 UIViewControllers: **A**, **B**, **C**. **A** is presenting **B** modally and **B** is presenting **C** modally. I have exit segue from **C** to **A** and everything works fine, but while dismissing controller **B** is flashing and it's `viewWillAppear` is called. 
Is it possible not to show **B** and don't call it's `viewWillAppear` in this situation?

Comment: Having been in a similar situation I would suggest dismissing B after C is presented, or dismissing B, then presenting C from A.

Answer (score 1):

Just a suggestion. Set alpha of view to 0 in `viewWillDisAppear` of `viewcontroller B` while presenting C from B. So while dismissing C to move back to A, `viewcontroller B` will not be visible. Again just a suggestion.